# Proper olive oil tasting technique

Tags: oil, tasting

I'm looking to buy some really nice olive oil from an artisan shop near my home. Is there an appropriate olive oil tasting technique, similar to wine? If so, what is it, and what dimensions of flavor and texture should I be mindful of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a fairly comprehensive "How to Taste" resource here:

> [The Olive Oil Source: How to Taste](http://www.oliveoilsource.com/page/how-taste)